# Javascript processing in browser or more processing server side

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, jetty

I currently have a web app using the google maps api. The app runs fine yet its abit laggy. Would it be more efficient doing more of the processing on the server and have loads more ajax requests or would trying to optimise the javascript be the way to go?

-------------EDIT-----------

The target device is a pi.

Basically the only computations is an map of colour : coordinated that gets looped over and then a map of x:y coordinates

So nutting majour. would it be better doing the loop client side or setting a timeout to do a request every say 100ms?

Comment: Long answer, it depends, short answer client is probably going to be faster.

Comment: There are lots of factors here and you have provided none of them. What kind of computation? How much? Split into lots of small functions or one large one? Where does the data for the computation come from? How large is the data in and out of the computation? Is it possible to execute the computation on the server given the available data?

Comment: Depends on your target device as well. If you're planning people to access it on a phone you might have a different answer than if you are targeting wired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.io to process the information you need and then send it to the client in realtime using websockets instead of ajax requests.

Comment: Backend is running a jetty http server, java